# EE Timesout when adding or deleting an entry

Tags: ee2, admin, channel-entries-api

I have upgraded from 2.1 to 2.11.6 and I am running into an issue from the admin control panel where if I add an entry or delete an entry it timesout.  I have the timeout set to 2 minutes.  It still will actually add the entry and delete it but it just hangs until it times out.  This is not happening when I do it on my local copy I have running.

I dug into it on the delete side of things and I have found a section in the /libraries/api/Api_channel_entries where it is hanging up.  There is a section roughly line 527 and if I comment it out things happen quickly as expected.  It deletes the entry earlier and then starts to do cleanup of other tables and gets hung up.

```
        foreach($ft_to_ids as $fieldtype => $ids)
    {
        ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_handler($fieldtype);
        ee()->api_channel_fields->apply('delete', array($ids));
    }
```

I am just looking for some guidance as I don't want to go in and change any core EE files and I have only been dealing with EE for under a year so not sure what may be the issue.

Any advice on where the issue may be so I can correct it would be appreciated.

Couple of updates.

I downloaded the database and files from the server and created a local copy so I know I have the same code and db as on my server and it takes 5-6 seconds to add a new article.  Still slow but can deal with it.  I set the timeout to be a lot longer and the process does complete on the server but it takes over 4 minutes.

Also should note that on my server I have 2 virtual servers behind a load balance with a single mysql instance on a third virtual.  I have it set to be cookie based security and not session based.  Wondering if that setup is what is causing the slow times.

Comment: What version of php are you using on your server?

Comment: PHP version = 5.6.29